# Distributing 3 white and 10 black marbles to 9 distinct boxes.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

**Question** In how many ways can you distribute 3 white and 10 black marbles (identical) to $9$ distinct boxes? 
**My attempt** $3$ white marbles can be distributed in ${3+9-1 \choose 3}={11 \choose 3}$ ways and $10$ black marbles can be distributed in ${10+9-1 \choose 10}={18 \choose 10}$ ways. So a total of ${11 \choose 3}{18 \choose 10}$ ways.
Is my solution correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks good to me, total of $165\times 43758 = 7220070$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

As you said, finding the ways to distribute the white and the black marbles is finding the ways to distribute the white marbles, and for each way, all the other ways to distribute the black ones.

With no more restriction (such as every box having to have one marble, or a maximum of marbles for box) that's it.

In case you are not sure of the ways of distributing the white marbles (or the black ones), you are simply using the [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) method, which is precisely the method for approaching this kind of methods.

Hoped it helped you to be more confident with your answer, though you solved it all by yourself.